# Which hypervisor allows mounting and editing virtual disks inside host Windows?

Tags: hard-drive, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware

I want to be able to have a complete control on the virtual disks that my virtual machine is going to use. Which hypervisor allows that? VMware, VirtualBox, Windows Virtual PC, etc.? I want to be able to mount those virtual HDDs and edit the files inside them and also manage those disks with a disk manager.

Comment: Virtual-PC isn't supported by Microsoft.  Windows has had native Hyper-V virtual hdd mounting support since Window 8.  Neither VMware or VirtualBox virtual hdds can be mounted natively

Comment: Why not to use NFS?

Comment: what is NFS? where can I find more info about it?

Comment: my win ver is win 10

Comment: Is it 64 bit version?

Comment: Hypervisors are necessary to *run* virtual machines.  It is completely independent of mounting a disk image.

Answer (score 1):

Before I start answering, I must say [this looks like an XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Your concern seems to be mounting a virtual hard disk in Windows. So, why do you tie it to a certain hypervisor?

1. Starting with Windows 7, Windows can mount (as well as create) virtual hard disk files in VHD format. (This it the format that many hypervisors can use.) In Windows 8 and later, the VHDX format is also supported. To mount, you have to use either the Disk Management snap-in or `diskpart`. Starting with Windows 10 v1511, mounting by double-clicking the VHD or VHDX file is also possible.
2. VMware Workstation can mount its own virtual hard disk format, VMDK.
3. Like I said, you don't need to restrict yourself to hypervisors. Daemon Tools, OSFMount and Winmount can mount virtual disk images.